# Return large data members of a class by reference or value

Tags: c++

In a getter type method I wonder which is best, opinions on this seem to vary because on the one hand you break encapsulation by returning by reference but on the other hand there is a lot of overhead to return by value if you intend the member to be mutable in the first place. Would it not be best to always return by reference in these situations and let the callee decide if he wants to make a copy or not depending on context?

Comment: IMO, always pass large objects by const reference or reference.  Prefer reference over pointer.

Answer (score 3):

I believe returning a const reference would be your best option. This way you'll avoid the overhead of copying a large amount of data, but will also not allow changes from the outside.

Comment: There's forced RVO nowadays.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: He's returning data members.

Comment: I understand the idea of returning const references but what about the scenario where you need the member to be mutable from the outside?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I don't see any particular code in question?

Comment: navark: Well then there is no question about returning by value or reference. You can't return by value if you want to be able to change it. You should just return a reference. The standard way of doing it is writing two getters - a const getter returning a const reference and a non-const getter returning a non-const reference.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It's in plain English. In both the title and the body.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Since when does _plain english_ replace code now. Are yous people going crazy now since _brexiting_??

Comment: @grigor I was considering creating a setter method to change the member from a different object (a copy) to keep the encapsulation but if you say this is the standard way then good I didn't want to have to deal with the performance hit just to adhere to the strict OO design I learned in school either.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Your comment makes no sense. He's asking for what kind of code he should write. He's not asking about a problem caused by code he has. What code do you expect to see, and how would it be relevant to the question or this answer?

Comment: @navark Yes at least this is how it's done in STL. For example, the `vector` class has two operators [] - a const version and a non-const one, for accessing it's elements. That's how you can do e.g. `a[0] = 5;` where a is a `vector<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

Modern compilers can optimize returning by value and remove any copy/move overhead[1][2]. So you don't have to worry about that.

Deciding to have a copy or returning a reference should be the API designer rule not the client, you should tell if this object should be mutable or not and define your API according to the use cases of this class and its requirements that it should fulfill.

---

[1. Copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

[2. RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Comment: My understanding of RVO is it would apply on returning local variables in the method but not on class member variables no?

Comment: oh yes, you are right